# what gcc intermediate file res for

Tags: file, gcc, temp

when compile c source file with gcc, I find gcc generates follow  intermediate

```
files:ccNcs24W.s, ccUHAuzr.o and cchsVb5V.res.
```

I know what the first two files for, but who can tell me what the last res file for?

Comment: What platform, version? Please also provide a [mcve].

Comment: ubuntu1~16.04.4， gcc version 5.4.0 20160609